# Android AlertDialog won't dismiss when aux cord is unplugged

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-broadcast

I want an `AlertDialog` message to appear when the user plugs in an aux cord. I want the alert message to disappear when the user unplugs the auxiliary cord. I don't want the user to able to get rid of the `AlertDialog` message until he/she unplugs the aux cord. So far, my `BroadcastReceiver` works with `Toast`. But it does not work with `AlertDialog`.

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver; 
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;


 public class AuxChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 @Override 
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     AlertDialog.Builder removeAux = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
            switch (state) {
            case 0:
                removeAux.setOnDismissListener( new OnDismissListener() {
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        if (state==0) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });

                break;
            case 1:
                removeAux.setMessage("Unplug Aux!").create().show();
                break;
            default:
                Toast toast3 = Toast.makeText(context, "No clue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast3.show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code working with `Toast`, but I don't want a `Toast`:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;


 public class AuxChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 @Override 
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
            switch (state) {
            case 0:
                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(context, "There is no aux cord detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast1.show();
                break;
            case 1:
                Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(context, "Aux Cord Detected, Please unplug it!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast2.show();
                break;
            default:
                Toast toast3 = Toast.makeText(context, "No clue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast3.show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would be to create your `AlertDialog` in `onCreate()` as opposed to in the receiver so that you can show and dismiss it from anywhere within the activity - something like the following. Begin by declaring your `AlertDialog` like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
    private AlertDialog alertDialog;
```

Then in `onCreate()`:

```
alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Warning");
alertDialog.setMessage("Aux cord plugged in, please unplug...");
```

Then when the aux cord is plugged in (`case 1:`):

```
alertDialog.show();
```

And when the cord is unplugged (`case 0:`):

```
alertDialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: it worked! thanks @Willis In order to call alertDialog in my BroadcastReciver, I had to import. com.MyPackage.MyMainActvityName to my AuxChangeReceiver class. I had to set alertDialog to static and reference alertDialog in my Broadcast receiver like this: MyActivityName.alertDialog.dismiss();

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a method for alert dialog like this

```
 public AlertDialog CreateAlert(String title, String message) {
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alert.setTitle(title);
        alert.setMessage(message);
        alert.show();
        return alert;

    }
```

trigger the alert where you want by calling this method

```
CreateAlert("YOUR TITTLE", "YOUR MESSAGE");
```

Comment: thanks @krishnan ,but it doesnt recognize the context because this is a broadcast reciver. I dont have an oncreate method, so when i do AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();. i throws an error for "this"